# Show button for capture under camera roll with UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, camera

Several apps such as Facebook allows you to start the camera from the camera roll in the upper left hand corner when inside an image picker. The `UIImagePickerController` as it is doesn't show the camera button. Do I need to create a custom picker in order to achieve this or is there a property I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook app's image picker view controller is completely customized from the ground up. You can use set UIImagePickerController's "sourceType" to UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera, and also "showsCameraControls" to YES, to use a customized UIImagePickerController, but yet you can't achieve the same level of customization as Facebook's app does. So, if you want something like Facebook app's image picker, you can either create it yourself, or, search for a third party open source library for that.

Comment: I've taken a look at `ELCImagePickerController` and `QBImagePickerController`, but they didn't seem to support capturing image from the camera roll itself either, despite allowing me to select multiple images.

Comment: Personally, I suppose it won't be difficult to implement a solution by yourself completely. If you don't want to, check if you can modify 3rd party library (if there're source code) to suit your own purpose.